# MySQL 5 - How to Set a Special Character of ć Inside a Cell in MySQL 5?

Tags: mysql

In my local instance of a MySQL 5 database, I need to have a special character displayed for a specific id for a row in the database, so when I display the actual row's cell (name) that I need to update:

```
SELECT name FROM user_table WHERE id = 1;
```

The query results in:

```
Andres Lukic
```

But I need to update it using the special character over the "c" like this "ć";

So the same query would result in:

```
Andres Lukić
```

When I tried the following SQL Update statement:

```
UPDATE user_table SET NAME = "Andres Lukić" WHERE id = 1;
```

The query results were still unchanged:

```
Andres Lukic
```

How can I set this cell's value appropriately in MySQL?

What is the command / query that shows the current supported charset / encoding?

Answer (score 0):

are you using `utf8_general_ci` as Collation ?

During my test it is working as you given above.

[image]

Comment: how can I check for that?

Comment: Please check my attached screen.

Answer (score 0):

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename;
```

This will show you the default charset at the last line.
Also check if your MySQL client supports special characters and it's charset 
settings are correct.

Comment: This is what it shows me: ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1, how can I change this to the right value for the entire database and / or table?

Comment: Table:
`ALTER TABLE tablename CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8;`
Database:
`ALTER DATABASE db_name
    [[DEFAULT] CHARACTER SET charset_name]
    [[DEFAULT] COLLATE collation_name]`
The collate should be `utf8_general_ci` or `utf8_general_cs` (case insensitive / sensitive).